# Split string on first space occurance in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv

I have a column that contains first and last names like these.

```
word1 word2
word1 word2 word3
word1 word2
```

I need to split string on first space occurance.

```
|word1| |word2|
|word1| |word2| |word3|
|word1| |word2|
```

can someone help me thanks

Comment: Other than the added pipes, how is your output any different from the input?

Answer (score 2):

You split the column into an array:

```
select string_to_array(words, ' ') as words_array
```

You can put this in separate columns if you like, but I would move the `string_to_array()` to the `from` clause:

```
select word_array[1], word_array[2], word_array[3]
from t cross join lateral
     (values (string_to_array(t.words, ' '))) v(word_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Alessio answer, I improved its query to be compatible with row that have only one element like, because its query crash in this case :

```
word1
word1 word2
word1 word2 word3
```

to be splitted as :

```
word1 | NULL
word1 | word2
word1 | word2 word3
```

The query is :

```
UPDATE "my_table" SET "col_1" = split_part("col_name", ' ', 1)), "col_2" = substring("col_name",(length(split_part("col_name",' ',1)))+1,(length("col_name")) - (length(split_part("col_name",' ',1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many words there are in the sentence, for the first word it is simple I think.

```
SELECT split_part(colName,' ',1);
```

For everything else after the first space it becomes a bit more complicated.
You can use math or regular expression. I think something like good old math can work.

```
SELECT substring(colname,(length(split_part(colname,' ',1)))+2,(length(colname)) - (length(split_part(colname,' ',1))+1));
```

Or you can use the function `select regexp_replace` with regular expression

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed maximum number of elements per string, you can use split_part()`:

```
select 
    split_part(col, ' ', 1) as word1, 
    split_part(col, ' ', 2) as word2,
    split_part(col, ' ', 3) as word3
from mytable
```

An alternative uses arrays:

```
select x.arr[1] as word1, x.arr[2] as word2, x.arr[3] as word3 
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values (string_to_array(t.col, ' '))) x(arr)
```

This might be more efficient because the string is parsed only once.